# Video glasses suitably capable of reading pdf

Tags: display, screen

We have seen a couple of RPi + video glasses combo's the last year. A lot of them wanted some kind of AR result, with a monocular display. My use case, however, would be different. Basically, I would like to be able to do some

- PDF reading (A4 / US letter),
- work in a terminal.

Further, I would like to do this while waiting for my train and during my commute. Especially the "waiting for the train (standing)"-scenario would profit from video glasses (as opposed to tablets and laptops).

**Note:** I really want to do this with non-Apple, non-Google, non-(big company trekking my whole life) stuff. (So no semi-Android powered glasses, etc...)

Since the terminal work I want to doesn't put large constraints on the resolution, we can basically leave it out of consideration.

---

I am particularly impressed by http://www.instructables.com/id/RaspberryPi-Powered-Wearable-Computer/ (using the Vuzix Wrap 920, 640x480).

Based on my experience with reading PDF's on my Nokia N900, I think 800x480 is just a little bit to small. I want to be able to read without sideways scrolling (but an entire page on screen is not needed). This gives me the impression that the Vuzix Wrap 1200 (852x480) might just be big enough (though I think it is on the edge).

I would like to hear if people have other ideas. On Amazon there are a lot of other glasses and brands, but I guess most of them don't even come close to what they claim to do.

So all in all, I am looking for video glasses:

- compatible with the RPi,
- suitable for PDF reading,
- (USB-powered would be very cool, but not necessary).

Answer (score 0):

So just buy the V720 from the same company mentioned in your link. ( This is not a rpi specific question)